# Permission Denied Accessing SQL Server Master Database from Windows Service

Tags: sql-server

I have a Windows Service (running as Local System) and it needs to create/drop a database in the local SQL Server Express 2012. Doing so yields an error message:

> "CREATE DATABASE permission denied in database 'master'."

I can connect to the instance as a local administrator and create/drop databases. Doesn't Local System have sysadmin permission on the local SQL Server? If not, how do I grant it permission?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turned out Local System is not in the sysadmin group (only in the public group).

Comment: What was your final solution ?

Comment: I believe I added NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM to the sysadmin group (which should be in there in the first place according to https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/919023/sql-server-2005-connectivity-and-volume-shadow-copy-service-vss).